# How can I readonly attribute in Backoffice config.xml dynamic

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to set/unset readonly attribute of certain field in backoffice editor area based upon the property that is defined in local.properties.

I tried doing following:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="xyz" readonly="spring.getBean('configurationService').getConfiguration().getBoolean('make.me.readonly')"/>
```

but there was schema validation error and also it didn't change the field attribute.

Comment: You might need to use custom editor to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register "configurationService" so that it could be used in config.xml.
By default only the services mentioned in,
`platformbackoffice.available.bean.names.for.spel=labelService,enumerationService,exceptionTranslationService,backofficeTypeUtils` can be used within config.xml.

To include "configurationService" add the below piece of code to your backoffice-spring.xml.

```
<cng:list-extender bean="fixedBeanResolver" property="availableBeanNames">
    <cng:add value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>configurationService</value>
    </cng:add>
</cng:list-extender>
```

And then make the service call from config.xml,

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="xyz" readonly="@configurationService.getConfiguration().getBoolean('make.me.readonly')"/>
```